# where clause: if this value from col x make sure col y is this value

Tags: subquery, condition

[image]

I feel like this is an easy one for you Experts!  I haven't done any kind of Advanced SQL in years.

Fundamental question:

```
select
    *
from myTable
where ((if col1 = 'this', make sure col2 = 'that')
else, don't include it in the results)
```

I would want to include all of this in my result set EXCEPT the first row, because `where col1 = 'this'  col2 doesn't = 'that'`

I want to only check where `col1 = 'this'` .. other values I want to include in the results.

How do I do the above logic in SQL Oracle.  I don't want to use PL/SQL  just plain SQL.
I was thinking there was a clever way to do this without some weird if/then/else statement

Thank you,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
select * from myTable 
where colY = 'that' or colX <> 'this'
```

The standard implementation of any criteria specified as `A => B` is as `B or not A`

**Update**:

Using this CTE for sample data:

```
with myTable as (
    select N,colX,colY from ( values
         (1,'this','hey')
        ,(2,'this','that')
        ,(3,'yup', 'yerp')
        ,(4,'yup', 'that')
    ) myTable(N,colX,colY)
)
```

and this query from above:

```
select * from myTable 
where colY = 'that' or colX <> 'this'
```

yields (as required):

```
N           colX colY
----------- ---- ----
2           this that
3           yup  yerp
4           yup  that

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Pieter thanks for the quick response, but I fail to see how this is a solution:

I posted example data to help explain myself.
Hope this clarifies

Comment: @user45961: Run it and verify - the SQL I posted above will return your example rows 2,3,and 4, but not row 1.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE NOT (ColX = 'this' and ColY <> 'that')
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from mytable where colx='this' and coly='that';

Comment: That wouldn't be it because now i'm limiting all my results to colx and coly equaling those specific values.. I only want to check that  if colY = 'that' then colX = 'this' otherwise I want everything else to not be effected

Comment: So where (colx='this' and coly='that') or (coly!='that')

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to achieve this.

here is one

```
SELECT *, 
CASE 
WHEN (col1 = "this" AND col2 != "that") THEN
    TRUE
ELSE 
    FALSE
END AS notavail
 FROM `myTable` 
HAVING notavail = 0 
;
```

here is another

```
SELECT *, 
IF(col1 = "this",col2 != "that",0) AS notavail
 FROM `myTable` 
HAVING notavail = 0 
;
```

here is another

```
SELECT *
 FROM `myTable` 
WHERE (!(col1 = "this" AND col2 != "that"))
```

here is another

```
SELECT *
 FROM `myTable` 
WHERE (NOT(col1 = "this" AND col2 != "that"))
;
```

here is another

```
SELECT *
 FROM `myTable` 
WHERE NOT (col1 = "this" AND col2 != "that")
;
```

and maybe some more complex ones are still available... *cheers*